# how to pass password file to openssl srp

Tags: linux, openssl, embedded-linux, srp-protocol

I'm trying to pass password to the openssl srp through a file using -passin param as below but im getting errors.

```
openssl srp -verbose -passin file:password.srpv.attr -srpvfile password.srpv -add -gn 3072 user
```

and I'm getting the following error

```
Trying to read SRP verifier file "password.srpv"
error on line 1 of db attribute file 'password.srpv.attr'
SRP terminating with code 1.
3073517768:error:0E079065:configuration file routines:DEF_LOAD_BIO:missing equal sign:conf_def.c:362:line 1
```

can you suggest what mistake I'm making.
Thanks

Comment: And you've double-checked that the password is the first line of the `password.srpv.attr` file? And that the user has read permissions to the file?  [passin](https://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/openssl.html#PASS_PHRASE_ARGUMENTS)